# Preventing Telegram Bot Account Ban for Rapid Responses

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, rate-limiting, spam-prevention

I've developed a Telegram bot that rapidly responds to every message received on my account. However, after deploying this feature, my account got banned. I believe this might be due to the bot's quick response behavior being flagged as spam-like activity by Telegram's system.

Could someone help me understand how I can prevent this from happening? Are there specific rate limits or best practices I should follow to avoid triggering Telegram's anti-spam measures with a bot?